# Integration of selenium and HPQC

Tags: selenium-webdriver, quality-center, selenium-rc

What are the options available for integrating Selenium web driver .net framework with HP QC? I know API is available from QC but I am looking for existing frameworks or tools that I can use for same.

Comment: Did you google? There are many links about this topic.

Comment: Yes, I did. I could only find bumblebee as an option but I am trying to explore if other folks have existing experience with using any other tools and frameworks and their experiences.